# To match words with the same pronounciation elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to match words that spells different, but have the same pronounciation. Like "mail" and "male", "plane" and "plain".  Can we do such a matching in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the phonetic token filter for this purpose. Phonetic token filter is a plugin and it requires separate installation and setup. You can make use of this [blog](https://qbox.io/blog/improving-search-experience-by-using-email-tokenizers-ngram-and-phonetic-concepts-1) which explains in detail, how to set up and use phonetic token filter.

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for. Where can I get more information on another type of encoders?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [analysis phonetic plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic) for that task.

Let's create an index with a custom analyzer leveraging that plugin:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/phonetic -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "my_metaphone"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_metaphone": {
          "type": "phonetic",
          "encoder": "metaphone",
          "replace": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Now let's analyze your example using that new analyzer. As you can see, both `plain` and `plane` will produce the single token `PLN`:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/phonetic/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'plane'
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/phonetic/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'plain'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "PLN",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 5,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Same thing for `mail` and `male` which produce the single token `ML`:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/phonetic/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'mail'
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/phonetic/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'male'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "ML",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

I've used the `metaphone` encoder, but you're free to use any other supported encoders. You can find more information on all supported encoders:

- in the [Apache Codec documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/package-summary.html) for `metaphone`, `double_metaphone`, `soundex`, `caverphone`, `caverphone1`, `caverphone2`, `refined_soundex`, `cologne`, `beider_morse`
- in the [additional encoders](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic/tree/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/phonetic) for `koelnerphonetik`, `haasephonetik` and `nysiis`

Answer (score 0):

A solution which doesn't need a plugin is to use a [Synonym Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html). Example:

```
{
"filter" : {
    "synonym" : {
        "type" : "synonym",
        "synonyms" : [
            "mail, male",
            "plane, plain"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

You can also put the synonyms in a text file and reference that, see the documentation I linked to for an example.