# Elasticsearch: Search for Mayer / Maier / Meyer / Meier

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 2.4.3 and have person documents in my index "persons" with firstName and lastName as fields.

For example a person has the lastName "Mayer" and I want to find this person even if I type in "Meier", "Meyer" and so on....

Has someone any idea to solve this requirement?

**Update**

Here is my phonetic filter:

```
        "phonetic":{
            "type": "phonetic",
            "encoder": "metaphone",
            "replace":"false",
            "languageset": ["german"]
        }
```

I have a Person with "Mayer" and a Person with "Maier" ... searching for Mayer only is responsed with the Person "Mayer" and not "Maier"

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html - It would probably be something like the following expression: `M[ae][iy]er`

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35145238/4604579 (hint: using the phonetic analyzer plugin)

Comment: Well, what is the result of your phonetic filter for both terms? `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/persons/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d 'Mayer'`

Comment: Maybe you can try a match query with fuzziness.